# starting calicoctl container on coreos

Tags: coreos, rkt, calico

I have CoreOS beta (1153.4.0)

I'm trying to run calicoctl to check if my calico networking is properly configured. so I'm trying to run a calicoctl rkt container with the command `rkt run quay.io/calico/ctl` and I get the output

```
image: using image from local store for image name coreos.com/rkt/stage1-coreos:1.13.0
image: using image from local store for image name quay.io/calico/ctl
networking: loading networks from /etc/rkt/net.d
networking: loading network default with type ptp
[ 2147.433992] ctl[5]: Override the host:port of the ETCD server by setting the environment variable:
[ 2147.434626] ctl[5]: ETCD_ENDPOINTS [example: http://1.2.3.4:2379,http://1.2.3.5:2379]
[ 2147.435096] ctl[5]: or, if ETCD_ENDPOINTS is left unset:
[ 2147.435565] ctl[5]: ETCD_AUTHORITY [default: 127.0.0.1:2379]
[ 2147.436026] ctl[5]: Usage: calicoctl <command> [<args>...]
[ 2147.436502] ctl[5]:     status            Print current status information
[ 2147.436946] ctl[5]:     node              Configure the main calico/node container and establish Calico networking
[ 2147.437402] ctl[5]:     container         Configure containers and their addresses
[ 2147.437857] ctl[5]:     profile           Configure endpoint profiles
[ 2147.438316] ctl[5]:     endpoint          Configure the endpoints assigned to existing containers
[ 2147.438817] ctl[5]:     pool              Configure ip-pools
[ 2147.439269] ctl[5]:     bgp               Configure global bgp
[ 2147.439738] ctl[5]:     ipam              Configure IP address management
[ 2147.440194] ctl[5]:     checksystem       Check for incompatibilities on the host system
[ 2147.440698] ctl[5]:     diags             Save diagnostic information
[ 2147.441158] ctl[5]:     version           Display the version of calicoctl
[ 2147.441636] ctl[5]:     config            Configure low-level component configuration
[ 2147.442119] ctl[5]: See 'calicoctl <command> --help' to read about a specific subcommand.
```

trying to execute calico from the command line using `rkt run quay.io/calico/ctl --exec calicoctl` returns `stage1: failed to configure systemd: unable to find "calicoctl" in "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`

trying to exec `/bin/sh` to see what's going on there I get the output

```
image: using image from local store for image name coreos.com/rkt/stage1-coreos:1.13.0
image: using image from local store for image name quay.io/calico/ctl
networking: loading networks from /etc/rkt/net.d
networking: loading network default with type ptp
```

and then it quits.

any ideas?

## update

with latest version of calico-ctl I get a different error message:

```
# rkt run quay.io/calico/ctl --exec /calicoctl -- status
image: using image from local store for image name coreos.com/rkt/stage1-coreos:1.14.0
image: using image from local store for image name quay.io/calico/ctl
networking: loading networks from /etc/rkt/net.d
networking: loading network default with type ptp
[156164.470502] ctl[5]: Docker is not running
```

Comment: You need `--interactive` when you `--exec /bin/sh`

Answer (score 1):

Calicoctl is stored in the filesystem root `/`

The rkt run syntax isn't ideal, but here's how you can run it with additional arguments

`sudo rkt run quay.io/calico/ctl --exec /calicoctl -- version
image: using image from local store for image name coreos.com/rkt/stage1-coreos:1.12.0
image: using image from local store for image name quay.io/calico/ctl
networking: loading networks from /etc/rkt/net.d
networking: loading network default with type ptp
[360361.039942] ctl[5]: 0.22.0-dev`

Comment: hi. thanks for your response. running version with this method returns the proper version, but when trying to run status command, i get "ctl[5]: Docker is not running". any ideas?